# Bone weights won't show when selecting bone directly

Tags: weight-painting, rigify

I've used rigify to set up a rig, I've gone through all the steps to complete the rig. I have the bone weight vertex groups from the rig, which show fine when selecting the group directly. I have the metarig hidden so I'm not highlighting the wrong one. But when doing normal weight-painting of rig+model and then ctrl-clicking a bone, they all show as blank. This is how it's normally done and it's EXACTLY what tutorials say to do, down to following their exact keypresses. They all show as pure magenta unless I click somewhere. I've weight-painted a few times before so I know how it should work, but I cannot for the life of me understand what's going on or why this is a problem.

Yes, the rig controls the model, everything seems to have worked, there was no error that I saw. I simply can't show weights by clicking the bones in weight-painting mode.

I'm at my wit's end due to a complete lack of any information on anything like this.

Please help me.

Blender3.1.0 for note.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've selected a bone with an property that disallows geometry deformation. All deformable bones have a prefix of ***DEF-*** and they appear when turning on the 30th armature visible layer.